# Hadoop crashes on reduce step java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: hadoop, solr, nullpointerexception, reduce, nutch

I'm using hadoop 1.1.2, Hbase0.9 Nutch 2.2.1 and Solr.
Everithing works fine when i use Nutch without hadoop.
I can start a single node cluster without any problems,
When i try to crawl in single node mode with hadoop i get this warning

```
17/12/08 14:42:30 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
```

and then, during reducing job i get these errors

```
17/12/08 14:42:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
17/12/08 14:42:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 50%
17/12/08 14:43:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 66%
17/12/08 14:43:08 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :       
attempt_201712081441_0002_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.<init>(Utf8.java:37)
at  
org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:650)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

I'm using java 6 cause with java 8 i get the same error and others warnings.
To perform the crawl i use this command

```
 hadoop jar apache-nutch-2.2.1.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 2
```

Comment: is this the contents of your task attempt (for attempt_201712081441_0002_r_000000_0) log?

Comment: No, this is what i get as output in my terminal when i use the command line written in the bottom of my question. As you can see it crashes when reducing job is at 66%. It always crashes at 66% or 33%

Comment: Can you post any errors in the task log?

Answer (score 0):

i have three log files in

```
$HADOOP_HOME/logs/userlogs/job_201712081441_0002/attempt_201‌​712081441_0002_r_000‌​000_0
```

that are:

`log.index`

`LOG_DIR:$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/../logs/userlogs/job_201712081441_0002/attempt_201712081441_0002_r_000000_0`

```
stdout:0 -1

stderr:0 -1

syslog:0 -1
```

The others are `sys.log` (that have the same output as the shell) and 2 others empties files.